# Permission issue while accessing Share from IIS

Tags: network-shares, iis, smb

Here is the abbreviated version:

I have a dot net application running under IIS.  When I do a `File.Move(local file, remote share file)` the Move does not happen and there is an SMB error "Security Blob: <MISSING> NO DATA" error.

The File.Move() does not return (it hangs), I had to get the error using Wireshark.

I replaced the File.Move() with a .bat script running ROBOCOPY executed from dotnet.  It hung as well.  But I could run the bat script on the command line and it would copy the file.

I used `whoami` in the bat script to confirm the exact same user was executing it regardless of what started the .bat script.

I am pretty convinced that IIS adds a "secret" layer of security to fileio.  I want to know how to overcome this.

---

I have a folder shared from a server (192.168.2.1) that is not on the domain.

Let's call that `\\\192.168.2.1\PropDocsLib`.

I want to access that shared folder from a dot.net program running under IIS on a different server (newwebserver) that is on the domain.

I can access that share if I use windows explorer from NewWebServer, but when I use IIS the files in the share are not visible.  I have used all kinds of different calls in the code (`File.Exists()`, `FileSystem.Rename()`, `File.Move()`) but the files are not visible.

Each of those calls hangs as tho it is waiting for credentials.

I also wrote a .bat script to execute a ROBOCOPY.  If I run the bat on the commandline it works, but if execute it under IIS it hangs on the ROBOCOPY.

I am now trying to use VirtualDirectories in IIS to give me access to the share from IIS.  This blurb seems to allude to that is possible:

[image: Virtual Directory As Solution to Permissions in IIS]

When I try to configure the VD I see this:

[image]

How do I enter the credentials for the other machine (it is not on the domain)?

When I try 192.168.2.1\Administrator I get wrong password.

Any other tips on setting on this screen?  I can not find the documentation on what each of these do:

[image]

[EDIT]
I can connect to the share using windows explorer using `Webserver\Administrator` and the password, but when Attempt to connect to it using a Virtual Directory I get this:

[image]

[EDIT]
We tried running the Pool with identity .\Administrator and mapping drives (X:, Y:, and Z:) with the shares that we are trying to use.  We can access those drives while logged in as .\Administrator using windows explorer.  But IIS does not allow us to access them.

[EDIT] We used Wireshark to see the exact error that was being thrown by the attempted access to the share:

[image: SMB error from Wireshark]

Where the significant part is "Security Blob: : NO DATA".

That pointed us to:
Extend Security Authentication.

I am going to add the SMB tag and hope someone looks at it.

Comment: Since you suspect this is an SMB error, what version of SMB, is the server configured to use?  Difficult to diagnose an error like this without any information on any of the clients and/or server.

Comment: A newbie gave an answer that looked like it had good information in it about registry entries for SMB. Could someone find that and post it back as a comment?

Comment: [This](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc772979(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) was the link.

Comment: SMB error would mean a total loss of access. That's not it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark but there is a slight possibility that the File operations inside of the app pool require the local user profile when reading over the network for some reason.  In app pool advanced settings, try setting Load User Profile = true.  This adds access to all the special folders that might be needed to help shuttle data like %appdata%, etc.  It's possible that the network protocols need that when shuttling data and maybe that's why it works through windows explorer but not through the IIS app pool.

Comment: I did not get a chance to try this answer as I went a completely different route on a solution.  I am awarding the bounty solely on votes.

Answer (score -2):

Ensure that you are using an up to date version of SAMBA.

---

When creating the virtual directory, you had the possibility of using the
"Connect as..." button to setup "Pass-through authentication".

Pressing the button enables setting "Path credentials" to either one of
the following two options:

1. Specific user : A specified local account
2. Application user (pass-through authentication) : Use the application-pool identity

The second option is the default, but will probably not work over the network.
You need to use the first option and specify an account that has the
right to access the specified remote share over the network.

---

You could also change the Application Pool Identity to one that can access
the network.

Be careful to use an account that only has local permissions on the folders
it really needs to use.

---

For running a command such as robocopy with RunAs another account,
avoiding the need to input interactively the password,
one solution would be to use
[RunAsSpc](http://www.robotronic.de/runasspcEn.html)
with which you may call a program, requiring a password, where
the password and other details are kept by RunAsSpc in an encrypted database.
RunAsSpc is free for private use.

For more details about using it see the article
[Pass the password to Runas with RunAsSpc](http://www.robotronic.de/guidance.html).

---

When programming in IIS the access to external computers,
you could change the user-account used by IIS for the duration only,
to an account that is authorized to access the network,
afterward reverting to the original IUSR account of IIS.

This solution always worked flawlessly for me.
Its great weakness was the need to use in IIS the user-name and password
in plain-text, which can be avoided by storing them in encrypted format,
unencypted only during their use.

Using C or any language that can invoke Windows API functions,
you would use the
[ImpersonateLoggedOnUser function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-impersonateloggedonuser)
to change the account token that is attached to the current IIS instance,
and also for reverting it.

Comment: Yup, that is what I am trying to do.  You can see the Physical Path Credentials is Administrator, but I need to know how to set it such that it can read the Share on the remote computer.

Comment: Use an account that has the permission to read the share on the remote computer. In other words, assure that the account has that permission. The simple way is to have on both computers an account with the same name and password.

Comment: Yeah, I am testing dozens of combinations trying to find the combination that will work it is quite tedious.  I can set "Path credentials" so a particular user that I would expect to work because I can use that same user to browse to the share using windows explorer.  There must be something additional that needs to be done to allow the shares to be read by IIS.  The complication I am facing is the sharing machine is not on the domain.

Comment: Are you saying that if I create a user on each machine named MyNewUser and set the password the same on both machines and enable read/write permission of the share on the remote machine, and set user on the application pool to that user that you would expect that to work?  That essentially what I have done with the local administrator account.

Comment: I think my answer now contains all the possibilities, in spite of the downvotes.

Comment: thanks for the effort on this answer.  The bounty will expire soon; I would award you the bounty for the effort, but I am going to give it to @madamission as he seems new to SO and his answer has higher votes.

Comment: Votes isn't everything.

Comment: I know brother, but let's give the new guy a break.

Comment: The downvotes on this answer are uncalled for.  harrymc's suggestions were good guesses for such a mysterious problem.

Comment: They are not guesses - I have done them with success several times and could have even contributed code fragments. A pity that this exceeded the knowledge and experience of some readers.

Comment: Yeah, I could have chosen my words more carefully; I was referring to that they are a guess as to whether they would solve my problem.